# PDO::exec() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code that makes the error:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO pedidos (pagado, instalado) VALUES ("'.$_POST['email'].'", "'.$_POST['b'].'") WHERE email="'.$_POST['2'].'"';
$stm = $conn->prepare($sql);
$conn->exec($stm);
```

Comment: See also [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174) (which is not just about security, but about getting things to work correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the proper way to use prepare and execute. The reason this was created was so that you wouldn't need to put logic and data together and put yourself at risk of an SQL injection attack.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO pedidos (pagado, instalado) VALUES (:pagado, :instalado)';
$stm = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stm->bindParam(':pagado', $_POST['email']);
$stm->bindParam(':instalado', $_POST['b']);
$stm->execute();
```

It also doesn't make sense to put a WHERE in an INSERT query. You're inserting into your table, you're not getting data.

However, if you're updating data based on other data, then you should use an UPDATE query.

```
UPDATE pedidos SET pagado=?, instalado=? WHERE email=?
```

An example of this would be:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE pedidos SET pagado=:padago, instalado=:instalado WHERE email=:email';
$stm = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stm->bindParam(':pagado', $_POST['email']);
$stm->bindParam(':instalado', $_POST['b']);
$stm->bindParam(':email', $_POST['2']);
$stm->execute();
```

Comment: Are you updating columns? If so, you need a different query entirely.

Comment: You forgot writing this: WHERE email="'.$_POST['2'].'" Yes im, its the first query i make so i need help

Comment: @JuanPerez Looks like you're trying to update data instead, can you try the updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE - 2:**

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO pedidos SET pagado = ?, instalado = ? WHERE email = ?';
$stm = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stm->bindParam(1,$_POST['email']);
$stm->bindParam(2,$_POST['b'] );
$stm->bindParam(3,$_POST['2'] );

$stm->execute(); // here your code generate error
```

**Reason:** You put `$stm` in `execute()` , which makes an **error**.

Comment: Now it gives this error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute()

Comment: change `$conn->execute()` to `$stm->execute()` will resolve your issue

Comment: Last error, not about this, its a syntax error en $sql in the part of WHERE, could you tell me why?